# Video on demand - streaming only a segment of a video, and viewing in HTML5

Tags: red5

Wondering if I can use red5 to stream parts of an existing video (not a live feed). Say I have a 2hr video, and I want to stream only a 30 second clip starting at 1hr5min, is that a request red5 can handle?

My app would be in HTML5 + PHP (lamp).

Answer (score 2):

There's a matter of focus in this question. You're mixing two different things:

- In one hand, you want to use red5 for VoD. This software makes uses of Adobe Flash protocols to serve its content.
- In the other hand you want to use html5 to read this stream. Html5 was made to get rid of Adobe's de facto standard.

To use html5 you should aim to streaming platafforms which uses web-friendly technologies. Check this out to see the different formats and its support in the different browsers.

http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

VLC can be a good start point for you:

https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/VLM#Video_On_Demand